# Looking for certain fields in a JSON file at a URL

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm having trouble getting the gist of JSON and Java objects working together. Basically what I need to do is check a JSON file at a URL to see if there is an updated version of software available to use. I've opened the connection and can print out the JSON to the console but that's all I've had luck with. I've been trying to make use of GSON mostly. Below is the main code I have so far, with manifest being an object of the class shown farther down. I'm mostly concerned with the "version" field(s) in the JSON, as I need to compare that to my current program version number.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()));
stringV = reader.readLine();
//System.out.println(manifest);
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringV = stringV + gson.toJson(line);
    //manifest = manifest + line;
}
System.out.println(manifest);

manifest man = gson.fromJson(manifest, manifest.class);
testString = man.getversion();
System.out.println(test);
```

One of my questions involves the class I dedicated for the JSON, do I need to have declarations, get/set, for all of the fields in the JSON?

```
public class manifest{
    private List<String> versions;
    private String version;
    private String current;
    private String compatible;
    private String published;
    private String description;
    private List<String> manifest;
    private String jre;

    public List<String> getVersions(){return versions;}
    public String getversion(){return version;}
    public String getcurrent(){return current;}
    public String getcomp(){return compatible;}
    public String getpub(){return published;}
    public String getdesc(){return description;}
    public List<String> getFileList(){return manifest;}
    public String getjre(){return jre;}

    public void setVersions(List<String> versions){this.versions = versions;}
    public void setversion(String version){this.version = version;}
    public void setcurrent(String current){this.current = current;}
    public void setcomp(String compatible){this.compatible = compatible;}
    public void setpub(String published){this.published = published;}
    public void setdesc(String description){this.description = description;}
    public void setFileList(List<String> manifest){this.manifest = manifest;}
    public void setjre(String jre){this.jre = jre;}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Versions:%s,version:%s,curr:%s,comp:%s,pub:%s,desc:%s,manifest:%s,jre:%s", 
                versions, version, current, compatible, published, description, manifest, jre);
    }
}
```

Here's the structure of the JSON:

```
      {
       "versions": [
          {
        "version": "II V7.1.2",
        "current": true,
        "compatible": true,
        "published": "2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00",
        "description": "Stability improvements for users:\n\n-Fix a crash\n-Fix a bug",
        "manifest": [
            {
                "name": "file.jar",
                "checksum": "56116165156111156156116161651161616116165116116516651651"
            }, (more elements here)
         "jre": "1.7.0_17"
```

Any help is very much appreciated, as I'm not familiar with JSON at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is actually very easy to conceptualize in an object world. You can think of it as being a map of data, where the keys are strings, and the values may be any of a primitive type (boolean, number, string, date), an array, or another map. Whenever the value ends up being another map then you create an object! It's that simple.

So in your case, lets look at the JSON snippet you included:

```
{
    "versions": [
        {
            "version": "II V7.1.2",
            "current": true,
            "compatible": true,
            "published": "2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00",
            "description": "Stability improvements for users:\n\n-Fix a crash\n-Fix a bug",
            "manifest": [
                {
                    "name": "file.jar",
                    "checksum": "56116165156111156156116161651161616116165116116516651651"
                }
            ],
            "jre": "1.7.0_17"
        }
    ]
}
```

The outer JSON object in this snippet contains a single JSON element, which is an array, with name `versions`. Each element in this array maps naturally to an object, giving you a top level definition like this:

```
public class Root {
    private List<Version> versions;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Now, you can start to look at the details of the `Version` object. Use these rules to create your Java object:

- Map each primitive type value to an equivalent Java property.
- Map object type values to classes.
- Map arrays to a Java collection type

*Dates are not primitive, but for purposes of mapping we will apply the same rule*

```
public class Version {
    private String version;
    private Boolean current;
    private Boolean compatible;
    private Date published;
    private String description;
    private List<Manifest> manifest; // Note the collection *and* object mapping
    private String jre;
    // Constructors, getters, setters
}

public class Manifest {
    private String name;
    private String checksum;
}
```

Pretty simple right? You would then map your top level JSON, to your top level object, with the following code:

```
Root obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, Root.class);
```

---

On a total side note, the code you are using to retrieve the JSON has some unnecessary/incorrect code:

- Use a `StringBuilder` to build up your string, rather than the more expensive concat operation
- In the while loop, the call to `gson.toJson(line);` is unnecessary and actually incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes more sense now.

Comment: After that, to get certain fields of information from the JSON object would you recommend using a parser? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: After you convert it to a Java object you do not need to do any additional parsing, just access the properties of the object same as you would any other.